# Socket IO connection issue in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to make a socket connection in NodeJS App.
I tried to run this code

### index.js

---

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8000)

const users = {};

io.on('connection', socket =>{

    socket.on('new-user-joined', name =>{ 

        users[socket.id] = name;

        socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined', name);
    });

    
    socket.on('send', message =>{
        socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {message: message, name: users[socket.id]})
    });

 
    socket.on('disconnect', message =>{
        socket.broadcast.emit('left', users[socket.id]);
        delete users[socket.id];
    });
});
```

### client.js

```
const user = prompt("Enter your name to join");
socket.emit('new-user-joined', user)

socket.on('user-joined', user =>{
    append(`${user} joined the chat`, 'right')
})

socket.on('receive', data =>{
    append(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`, 'left')
})

socket.on('left', user =>{
    append(`${user} left the chat`, 'right')
})
```

But I am not getting correct results and any errors in console.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not getting correct results" ? Can you explain what you expect and what is happening ?

Comment: After entering the name from prompt, it should display this"${user} joined the chat" message. But I am not getting any output

Comment: I tested your console replacing the `append` function with a `console.log` and it's working for me. I got `console` messages when a user connect or disconnect ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

var socket = io();


const user = prompt("Enter your name to join");
socket.emit('new-user-joined', user)

socket.on('user-joined', user =>{
    append(`${user} joined the chat`, 'right')
})

socket.on('receive', data =>{
    append(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`, 'left')
})

socket.on('left', user =>{
    append(`${user} left the chat`, 'right')
})
```

please  get a socket connection in HTML.

Which problem you face please briefly explain.
Thankyou.

```
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).